# Ansible gzip and gunzip data file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to gzip and unzip the data file. for unzip failed with `Command \"/usr/bin/gtar\" could not handle archive error` message.

created the test data file.
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test.dat bs=4k iflag=fullblock,count_bytes count=10M`

here is the playbook I am using.

```
cat test-archive.yaml
- name: Define sfgroups file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: Archive file
      archive:
        path: "/tmp/test.dat"
        dest: "/tmp/test.dat.gz"

    - name: Unarchive file
      unarchive:
        src: "/tmp/test.dat.gz"
        dest: "/var/tmp"
```

### How can we run the gunzip the file?

gzip didn't work, I changed play book to use `zip` format.

```
- name: Define sfgroups file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: Archive file
      archive:
        path: "/tmp/test.dat"
        dest: "/tmp/test.dat.zip"
        format: "zip"

    - name: Unarchive file
      unarchive:
        src: "/tmp/test.dat.zip"
        dest: "/var/tmp"
```

thanks
SR

Comment: It seems you can't and won't be able to unless you fix it yourself: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3241

Comment: thanks for info info @techraf I will try different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing arbitrary compressed data (.dat.gz) with a structured file archive (.tar.gz or .tgz).

Create `test.tar` with `tar cf test.tar test.dat`, gzip it if you like, and *then* hand it to ansible.

Comment: @techraf right, I don't want to use tar. want to just gzip and gunzip the file.

Comment: Tar adds just a few bytes of overhead. But you don't want to use tar, ok, fair enough. The "unarchive:" clause of your playbook currently invokes gtar, as explained by https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/unarchive_module.html#notes

Comment: I want to use it for the mysql backup and restore.

Comment: If you keep the current playbook, and don't change ansible sources, then that won't work, based on https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/files/unarchive.py#L747 , since there is no handler for that.

Comment: since gzip giving the error. I used zip format it works  with playbook. I will go with this now.